# How to fix out-of-sync calendar?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sync, calendar

I'm using a rooted Samsung Galaxy S (Vibrant) running stock FroYo from T-Mo.

I sync my calendar on the phone with my Google Calendar.  I have several different calendars on Google, shared with different groups of people, and all are set to sync with my phone.  Everything has been perfect since I got the phone 4+ months ago.

Two days ago, within 30 minutes of adding a calendar event where everything looked fine, when I went to add another event I noticed that most of my calendar events were missing.  I usually use Jorte, and have been doing so with no problems.  I checked the stock calendar app and it's displaying a different sub-set of events.

Looking at both calendar apps plus Google calendar on my PC I see:

1. some events appear on the PC and in both apps (very few)
2. most events are missing on one app or the other
3. for a given calendar, some events will appear on one app but not the other (even on the same day)
4. there are events appearing on the stock app that don't appear on either the PC or in Jorte (for a calendar I have read-only access to)

It seems to me that something has corrupted the phone's cache of data.  Could this be possible?  How would I fix it?  This is a **huge** PITA -- I depend on my calendar for everything.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to try is to clear the data and cache for both apps and their storage (`Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications`) and then re-sync (possibly in the app, or in `Settings -> Accounts and sync`).

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked!